# How can I enable anonymous comments in OSQA?

Tags: django, comments, osqa

I am wondering about how to enable anonymous posting their comments for a question in OSQA website, like stackoverflow.com does. If the OSQA does not support this feature yet, can you please give me a short brief on how can I implement a such feature like that?

Comment: That's Open Source Question and Answer: http://osqa.net/

Comment: OSQA question on Stackoverflow. funny.

Answer (score 1):

OSQA doesn't provide that functionality at this point.

If you want to request that it be added, I suggest you visit the [OSQA meta forum](http://meta.osqa.net) and ask for it there.

Even better, put in a feature request in the [OSQA Jira bug/features site](http://jira.osqa.net).